# QGIS Plugin to inject headers on the fly

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Is it possible to create a QGIS Python Plugin, or even a standalone Python script, that listens for network requests, and, if they don't meet certain criteria, will inject some headers?

The requests in question are coming from the QGIS Client itself, and not an external Plugin.

In short, I'd like to continuously listen for network requests and manipulate them when needed.

Can this be accomplished with [QgsNetworkAccessManager](https://api.qgis.org/api/3.16/classQgsNetworkAccessManager.html) ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Do you want to intercept the requests qgis makes and then add some headers automatically?